# Worksheet_SelectionChange causes both Subroutines to run

Tags: excel, vba

I have

```
' When Selection is Changed
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Rem call the - Sort_Customers_Countries - Subroutine & call the - Go_First_Sheet - Subroutine
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("cel__Sheets_Formula")) Is Nothing Then
    Sort_Customers_Countries
    Go_First_Sheet
End If

Rem call the - Center_Resize_Image - Subroutine
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("col__Customer_Country_Flag")) Is Nothing Then
    Center_Resize_Image
End If

End Sub
```

The problem is when `cel__Sheets_Formula` is selected it runs both the `Sort_Customers_Countries` and `Go_First_Sheet` and also `Center_Resize_Image`

I suspect it has something to do with the `Target`. `cel__Sheets_Formula` is a single named cell and `col__Customer_Country_Flag` is a column named inside a table.

The named ranges do not intersect. `cel__Sheets_Formula='Customers Countries'!$F$1` and `col__Customer_Country_Flag=tbl__Customers_Countries[Customer Country Flag]`

Comment: Do the two named ranges intersect? Does _Sort_Customers_Countries_ or _Go_First_Sheet_ change the selection?

Comment: @Shrotter: No I checked. cel__Sheets_Formula = 'Customers Countries'!$F$1 and col__Customer_Country_Flag = tbl__Customers_Countries[Customer Country Flag]

Comment: Do any of the Subs you call make a change to the Selection?  That would re-trigger the event...

Comment: @TimWilliams: none of the Subs make a change to the selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

It appears the solution was

```
' When Selection is Changed
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim currentCell As Range
Set currentCell = ActiveCell

Rem call the - Sort_Customers_Countries - Subroutine & call the - Go_First_Sheet - Subroutine
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("cel__Sheets_Formula")) Is Nothing Then
    Sort_Customers_Countries
    Go_First_Sheet
End If

Rem call the - Center_Resize_Image - Subroutine
If Not Intersect(currentCell, Me.Range("col__Customer_Country_Flag")) Is Nothing Then ' ///// instead of Target
    Center_Resize_Image
End If

End Sub
```